# How to pass CGAffineTransform as function argument in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I'm subclassing an Objective-c class and overriding a superclass method:

```
override func drawWithTransform(m: CGAffineTransform) 
{
     CGPathMoveToPoint(path, &m, 5, 10);
}
```

But I get a compile error: Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'CGAffineTransform'

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass constant to `UnsafePointer` parameter. And function parameters are constant *by default*.

As a workaround, you can use [*variable parameters*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID172).

```
override func drawWithTransform(var m: CGAffineTransform) {
     //                         ^^^^
     CGPathMoveToPoint(path, &m, 5, 10);
}
```

OR, copy it to a variable in advance:

```
override func drawWithTransform(m: CGAffineTransform) {
     var _m = m
     CGPathMoveToPoint(path, &_m, 5, 10);
}
```